# pandas exclude total if has details

Tags: python, pandas

has DF like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Art': [210, 211, 212, 310, 420, 421], 'Sum': [300, 120, 180, 250, 650, 650]})
```

in table view

```
  Art  Sum
0  210  300  # this is total
1  211  120  # children for index 0
2  212  180  # children for index 0
3  310  250  # !!! this is Not total
4  420  650  # this is total
5  421  650  # children for index 4
```

the total line is line where `Art` ends `0` but no children that start with the same two digits.

Art `210` has children : **21**1, **21**2

Art `310` not has children no line start with **31**

Issue: need to remove total lines.

result need:

```
  Art  Sum
1  211  120
2  212  180
3  310  250  # !! this is Not total
5  421  650
```

how to do it?

Comment: can you explain a little bit more about*but no children that start with the same two digits.*

Comment: @Wen edit question with more details, Art 210 has children : 211, 212

Art 310 not has children no line start with 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index the *Art* column according to the first two digits and filter accordingly:

```
buckets = (df['Art'] // 10).value_counts()
df = df.loc[(df['Art'] // 10).isin(buckets.loc[buckets == 1].index) |
            (df['Art'] % 10 != 0)]
```

Which outputs:

```
   Art  Sum
1  211  120
2  212  180
3  310  250
5  421  650
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
>>> df[~(df.Art.astype(str).str.endswith("0") & df.Art.astype(str).str[:2].duplicated(keep=False))]
   Art  Sum
1  211  120
2  212  180
3  310  250
5  421  650
>>>
```

Explanation:

- `A=df.Art.astype(str).str.endswith("0")` : check which values end with 0
- `B=df.Art.astype(str).str[:2].duplicated(keep=False)` : check which values has two digits that were duplicated.
- C = negate A&B
- filter the dataframe with C as a mask.